# Why does SQL Server CONVERT of a DATE value to a date+time style not include a time?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, format, type-conversion

If I provide a date+time style to the CONVERT function I expect to get a result with a date and a time part.

If the expression to be converted is a DATE datatype there is no time part in the result. I understand that a DATE datatype does not have a time component but I expect to see a 00:00:00 time part in the result because I'm explicitly specifying a date+time style.

Is this right? Is it documented behaviour?

```
declare @d date = '20160519'
declare @dt datetime = '20160519'

select '109 - Default + milliseconds' as Style, convert(varchar(32), @d, 109) as date_expression, convert(varchar(32), @dt, 109) as datetime_expression union all
select '113 - Europe default + milliseconds', convert(varchar(32), @d, 113), convert(varchar(32), @dt, 113) union all
select '120 - ODBC canonical', convert(varchar(32), @d, 120), convert(varchar(32), @dt, 120) union all
select '121 - ODBC canonical (with milliseconds)', convert(varchar(32), @d, 121), convert(varchar(32), @dt, 121) union all
select '126 - ISO8601', convert(varchar(32), @d, 126), convert(varchar(32), @dt, 126) union all
select '127 - ISO8601 with time zone Z', convert(varchar(32), @d, 127), convert(varchar(32), @dt, 127)
```

And here's the output - notice no time element in the second column.

```
Style                                    | date_expression | datetime_expression
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
109 - Default + milliseconds             | May 19 2016     | May 19 2016 12:00:00:000AM
113 - Europe default + milliseconds      | 19 May 2016     | 19 May 2016 00:00:00:000
120 - ODBC canonical                     | 2016-05-19      | 2016-05-19 00:00:00
121 - ODBC canonical (with milliseconds) | 2016-05-19      | 2016-05-19 00:00:00.000
126 - ISO8601                            | 2016-05-19      | 2016-05-19T00:00:00
127 - ISO8601 with time zone Z           | 2016-05-19      | 2016-05-19T00:00:00
```

I'm currently on SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5548.0 (X64)

**Update**: I think the subtlety of the question is being missed by some people. I'm not asking how to convert a date to character data with or without a 00:00:00 time part, I'm asking *why* the time part is missing when converting a date to character data using a date+time style. From BOL;

> *style*
>   Is an integer expression that specifies how the CONVERT function is to translate expression.

When I use CONVERT to translate a DATE value into a character value using a date+time style I expect SQL Server to include a default 00:00:00 time part in the format prescribed by the style.

Consider the opposite; CONVERTing a DATETIME with a non-midnight time component to character data using a date only style *does not* include the time in the result. This seems inconsistent.

Comment: In which format you want the result ? What exactly you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what output you expect, but your assumption that you are explicitly specifying a date+time style output and sql server would have to convert the date to datetime, is wrong. Take 
`convert(varchar(32), @d, 113)` where @d is a DATE. A DATE type doesn't store any information about the time. Even 00:00:000 is an information, it is thou used as a default when converting between DATEs to DATETIME, but it is not a part of a DATE.

So you are converting a DATE to a varchar and you specify the century for example  113 (Europe default, including milliseconds). SQL Server basically takes your request and converts the date to the desired output, but doesn't display any time information as there is none in your DATE variable. As I said, because you only specify what format he should use for the conversion, not any conversion to a datetime format.

If you wish to have the time included, you would need to explicitly convert your DATE to a DATETIME first:

```
convert(varchar(32), CAST(@d AS DATETIME), 113)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but please see my update, the question is more subtle than this.

Comment: Then please read again my answer, I did point that exactly out. TLDR: A Date type doesn't store information about time, converting it to your desired format has no time output, because 00:00:00 is an information that is not stored in a "date"